# How do I enable spell checking for SO in IE8?

Tags: discussion, firefox, spelling, internet-explorer-8

When I access SO from home in Firefox (under Ubuntu), it underlines in red my spelling misteaks (and there are many). But when I use IE8 (under XP) on a different machine, I do not get that functionality.

Does anyone know how SO is doing that and why it might not be working in IE? All the other fancy Javascripty things work fine in IE, just not the spell checking.

Comment: I'm voting to close as "can no longer be reproduced" because today Internet Explorer is a very old browser and if you're still using it you should really switch to a recent browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spell checking is a browser specific feature.

It is not up to Stack Overflow to enable spell checking.  Just use a different browser.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that. I just assumed it was more wonderfulness from Atwood et al. FWIW, I did a web search and found IE7Pro which, despite its name, gives spell checking for IE8 as well. Although, funnily enough, it doesn't like 'al' even though 'et' is fine. +1 and accept for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: No problem. (11 chars should really be enough)

Comment: Maybe 'al' wasn't liked because it wasn't spelled 'Al', like any good proper noun. ;-D

Comment: This is **STILL** an issue with IE, even **EIGHT** years later (IE11)!! If you'd like a fix, you can download a spell check plug-in [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40289).